¿Cómo poner el valor de un input en el código para hacer un número random?
No soy programador pero me apasiona hacer mis propias páginas y códigos viendo los tutoriales, pero, estoy creando un número aleatorio, usando un código ajeno que encontré en internet, pero necesito saber como utilizar el número de un input para crear el numero aleatorio y no tener que hacerlo tantas veces. Por ejemplo, en este código o uno que haga lo mismo me gustaria utilizar el número del input código postal para que se genere el código complementario aleatorio.
Generar codigos aleatorios para registro:
function codigo_random($length = 6)
{
  $charset = "123456789019283746509756124380";
  $codigo = "08304" //QUE AQUI UTILICE EN NUMERO INTRODUCIDO EN UN INPUT en lugar del codigo 08304//
  for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
  {
    $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
    $codigo .= substr($charset,$rand,1);
  }
  return $codigo;
}


echo codigo_random(6);

¿Que quiero hacer?
Si yo coloco 08304 la secuencia de numeros es 08304997854 y en su lugar quiero que cada vez que una persona introduzca su código postal en el input ese número reemplace el 08304 y la secuencia sea la que corresponde aleatoriamente.

Saludos. Te sugiero veas prompt en javascript; desde luego ahí (ya que dices no eres programador) sería colocarlos en lugar de la asignación de "08304" que mencionas da un vistazo en https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt

Hola. Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Para qué quieres exactamente el número que hay en el input? Además, ¿por qué usas código PHP, cuando todo se pasa en el cliente? ¿por qué no lo haces a nivel de Javascript? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Seas programador o no, no cambia nada. PHP es un lenguaje de servidor, un INPUT existe en el cliente. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es buscar cómo pasar un dato del cliente al servidor, y a partir de ahí ya sabrás cómo usarlo... No es cuestión de ser X o Y, es cuestión de tener ganas de investigar, que es básicamente el 90% del trabajo de un programador en realidad.

Si no mal entendí, quieres hacer un código en base a un número introducido + uno aleatorio.
Solución 

Obtén el valor del input:

$codigo = document.getElementById(/*Id del input, en un string*/).value 
o en jQuery:
$codigo = $(/*Id del input, también en un string*/).val

Asignar el valor a una variable, en este caso $codigo:

$codigo = $codigo + $rand
No sé que librería estás utilizando, pero en teoría debería ser así
